# Can't create instance variable using before_suite method in miniTest

Tags: minitest

I want create a `@conn` before all test case and can be used for all test case so i did something like:

```
class SQLTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def self.before_suite                                                       
        @conn = PG.connect(dbname:'MapSwitcher',host:'localhost', user:'Lin')
    end
    def  test_employee_table_have_5_entries
        result = @conn.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees")
        assert_equal(result.getvalue(0,0).to_i, 5)
     end

end
```

And I got an error:

```
noMethodError: private method `exec' called for nil:NilClass
```

it seems like the `@conn` can't be accessed in the test case,

Answer (score 1):

```
class SQLTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @conn = PG.connect(dbname:'MapSwitcher',host:'localhost', user:'Lin')
  end

  def test_employee_table_have_5_entries
    result = @conn.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees")
    assert_equal(result.getvalue(0,0).to_i, 5)
  end
end
```